# What is sequential passaging?

Tags: microbiology, experimental-design

I have read a journal that describes sequential passaging with the purpose of measuring resistance development in bacteria. I would like to know more about how the method works ie. what does "passage" mean?

https://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v517/n7535/pdf/nature14098.pdf, Methods part, under resistance studies

Comment: Can you please link the article?

Comment: The word "passage" in biological research methods generally refers to transferring a part of a culture (cell/bacterial/animal) from old medium to new medium.

Answer (score 1):

I am normally reluctant to cite Wikipedia articles, however, the one for [Sequential or Serial Passaging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_passage) explains it quite nicely.

In short:

> In microbiology, sequential or serial passaging refers to the process
>   of growing bacteria or viruses in iterations. In essence this means
>   that a virus or a strain of bacteria will be isolated and allowed to
>   grow for a period of time. After the sample has grown for some time,
>   part of it will be transferred to a new environment and allowed to
>   grow for the same period of time.This process will be repeated as many
>   times as desired. The final product is studied, often in comparison with the original virus or bacterial strain to see whether it has evolved or any other changes have occurred.